# How do I make saving calculator like this?

Tags: javascript

Can some please help me with making a similar saving calculator just like this one at the bottom right corner of this page http://www.clickitrealtyinc.com/

[image: Savings Calculator]

I need to install something like this on my website and have no idea where to start.

Comment: Are you a programmer? Or are you just looking for some software you can install? If the latter, this isn't the right forum for you ... (though I wish you luck).

Answer (score 0):

[Very, very basic implementation.](http://jsfiddle.net/evYxL/1/) The user interface is pretty <strike>different</strike> ugly, but there you go.

The magic is the following formula:

```
output = (input - 599) * 0.03
```

That's going to be the heart of your app, no matter how you build it.

Comment: Sdleihssirhc, thank you so much for your help. If I want to get a close look to the example how would you advise to build it?

Comment: [This new version](http://jsfiddle.net/evYxL/2/) has more code, but that's just to make sure the numbers are formatted right. For all intents and purposes, it works the same way your example does. Getting it to look similar is going to require images of some kind, and because I hate making images, I didn't do that part.

Comment: Thanks again, I already have all images ready. Now my question is where would I put the HTML code and where the JavaScript? I'm sorry for harassing you so much, I know very little about this and trying to learn.

Comment: If you're asking where it should all go on your own site, it's hard to say without having a link to it. If your site isn't even live yet, then... idunno (Also, being harassed is no problem if we get the answer right, and that answer ends up being accepted. [Nudge nudge, wink wink, say no more.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jT3_UCm1A5I))

Comment: Hey, I love Monty Python! Okay, here is my test page http://www.hitchcockrealty.net/test-page.html please help if you can I'm about to give up with my experiment :(

Comment: [I didn't change the HTML at all](http://chrisshields.net/test/), just added the script tag immediately after the style. You should be able to find it pretty easily.

Comment: YOU ARE THE MAN!!!!! How can I ever thank you? Here it is looking pretty http://www.hitchcockrealty.net/test-page.html...... Q1. How can I increase the top number to $2 millions? When goes to over $1 Million you get this: $NaN.undifined...... Q2. How can I stop the top number on $20,000? Everything else is perfect.

Comment: I updated that same page to fix those two bugs. A pretty good "thank you" would be to accept the answer.

Comment: Perfect!....Not one, but A MILLION "THANKS" to you for all your help, patience and your time spend on this!